# How to Use ember-data Adapters Without Model Name in URL

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to pull data from an API (OMDb) whose endpoint does not include a 'namespace' or actually anything at all beside the root URL (http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&).

I know how to use an 'empty' namespace for the URL I'm calling so that the adapter isn't tacking on '/api' or anything similar...BUT I cannot figure out how to NOT have the model name added to the URL (i.e., I want the URL to be 'http://www.omdbapi.com/' rather than 'http://www.omdbapi.com/movie'.

The documentation I've read has dealt with a 'namespace' (e.g., '/api') or changing the model name to something else in the URL-- but I can't figure out how to have the adapter construct a URL with NO model in the URL...a 'naked' URL, if you will...

Answer (score 0):

Annnnnd I found the solution. :)

the 'pathForType' option lets you create a custom value for the 'type' (i.e., model name).  Just use an empty string to achieve a 'naked' URL:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx',
  pathForType: function(type){
    return '';
  }
});
```